# How do I fetch sub collection from firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna fetch the data inside the Guests like guestName. The code below I used it to fetch collection and it worked, but I have no idea how to fetch subcollection. I been trying but it's not working.

[image]

```
    body: CustomScrollView(
slivers: [
SliverPersistentHeader(pinned: true, delegate: SearchBoxDelegate()),
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

//I used this to fetch collection but it doesn't work with subcollection
stream: Firestore.instance
.collection("Guests")
.orderBy("Date", descending: true).snapshots(),
builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
return !dataSnapshot.hasData
? SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: Center(
      child: circularProgress(),
    ),
  )
: SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(
    crossAxisCount: 1,
    staggeredTileBuilder: (c) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      ItemModel model = ItemModel.fromJson(
          dataSnapshot.data.documents[index].data);
      return sourceInfo(model, context);
    },
    itemCount: dataSnapshot.data.documents.length,
  );
},
),
],
),

Container(
child: Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
      // this guestName i wanna fetch
        model.guestName,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14.0),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
),
```

Comment: A subcollection exists under a specific document. To read from a subcollection, you'll need to know the ID of the document that subcollection is under.  Do you know that in your code?

Comment: I made my subcollection under the same ID for the collection, and I did fetch the collection but I have no clue how to fetch the subcollection,

Comment: Firestore.instance
.collection("Guests")
.orderBy("Date", descending: true).snapshots(), I used this method to fetch the collection, but it doesn't work with subcollection

Answer (score 1):

To get a `CollectionReference` for a subcollection, you first need to have a [`DocumentReference` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) to its parent document, and then you can call `collection()` on that.

In your builder you have `dataSnapshot.data.documents[index]`, which gives you a [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), from which you can get a `DocumentReference` by calling `reference` on it.

So combined that'd be something like this in your builder:

```
dataSnapshot.data.documents[index].reference.collection("Guests")
```

I recommend always keeping the reference documentation handy that I linked above, as it's the easiest way to find this type of API path.